# How to transform the Promise approach to Observable in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I've reading about observables and the many advantages it has over Promise. I'm developing a infinite scroll on angular and I found this code: https://github.com/Hacklone/angular2-cool-infinite-grid but the implementation is done with Promises, so I want to rewrite the code but using Observable.
How to start? and then how to consume?

Here is a method used in the implementation:

```
private async getItems(fromIndex: number, numberOfItems: number): Promise<any[]> {
  try {
      const result = this.itemIterator.next(fromIndex, numberOfItems);
      if (!result) {
        return [];
      }
      if (typeof (result.value.then) === 'function') {
        return await result.value;
      }
      else if (result.value instanceof Array) {
        return result.value;
      }
      return [];
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  return [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
private async getItems(fromIndex: number, numberOfItems: number): Observable<any[]> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {

  try {
      const result = this.itemIterator.next(fromIndex, numberOfItems);
      if (!result) {
        observer.next([]);
        observer.complete();

        return;
      }
      if (typeof (result.value.then) === 'function') {
        let value = await result.value;
        observer.next(result.value);
        observer.complete();

        return;

      }
      else if (result.value instanceof Array) {
        observer.next(result.value);
        observer.complete();

        return;
      }
      observer.next([]);
      observer.complete();

  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    observer.next([]);
    observer.complete();
  }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Observable.fromPromise`? You can find documentation here http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise

Comment: But the Promise<any[]> will be preserved in all the code -there are a couple of methods with the same return type-, I want to take off this component and replace it with my own component written with Observables.